# unsigned int * in place of int

Tags: c, function, pointers

I declare and define a function as follows:

```
unsigned int doSomething(unsigned int *x, int y)
{
    if(1) //works
    if(y) //reports the error given below

    //I use any one of the ifs above, and not both at a time

    return ((*x) + y); //works fine when if(1) is used, not otherwise
}
```

I call the function from main() as follows:

```
unsigned int x = 10;
doSomething(&x, 1);
```

The compiler reports an error and a warning as follows:

```
passing argument 1 of 'doSomething' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]|

note: expected 'unsigned int *' but argument is of type 'int'|
```

I tried using every possible combination for the function return type, function call, as well as for the argument types. Where am I wrong?

Full code:

```
unsigned int addTwo(unsigned int *x, int y)
{
    if(y)
        return ((*x) + y);
}
int main()
{
    unsigned int operand = 10;
    printf("%u", addTwo(&operand, 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Was a typo. Corrected it, but the page does not show it.

Comment: Do you have a declaration before calling `doSomething` ?

Comment: Compiles fine on my Mac (GCC 4.6.3) with all warnings enabled (apart from `control reaches end of non-void function`).

Comment: @cnicutar:'doSomething' is called from main().

Comment: @user2053912, cnicular is asking not from where `doSomething()` is called, but for it's declaration. Do you a header file, or a declaration of this function before it's body?

Comment: gcc 4.4.3 on Windows.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs: I meant to say, the function is defined before main(), and is called from within it.

Comment: Can you post a complete sample of when you actually get the warning  (not mixed with code which does *not* cause it)? Including how you launch gcc?

Comment: are you sure that that is how you call the `doSomething` function ? The error suggests you are passing an `int` as the first parameter.

Comment: @Andreas I get an error for all cases. Even for doSomething(10, 1).

Comment: OP, does this compile? This is the test case I was using. http://pastebin.com/JrhQei4Y

Comment: @tangrs: It does compile.

Comment: @user2053912: doSomething(10,1) will not compile, because first argument is int. You need to cast it, or use the actual pointer.

Comment: It's probably something wrong with the code you're using then. Can you post the whole code? Or a compilable piece that gives that warning?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs: Again sorry. What I did was: unsigned int x = 10; doSomething(&x, 1);

Comment: @user2053912: Something fishy here :) Please post the full code.

Comment: @tangrs: It is pretty much the same. When I simply return *x, the program crashes.

Comment: With the "Full Code", I do not get the warning mentioned in the posting  (MingW gcc 4.6.2, `gcc -pedantic -Wall` (I get other warnings though: you need to `#include <stdio.h>` and you need to return something at the end of `addTwo()`, in case the if-condition is false). But other than that, the code compiles and executes fine

Comment: Works on Ubuntu with both gcc 4.3.4 and 4.4.3 as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try on my side once again!

Comment: Yep, full code works on OS X GCC 4.6.3 with no integer casting warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used gcc 4.4.3 on Windows as well.
This program compiles successfully and produce output "11":

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int doSomething(unsigned int *x, int y);

int main()
{
    unsigned int res = 0;
    unsigned int x = 10;

    res = doSomething(&x, 1);

    printf("Result: %d\n", res);

    return 0;
}

unsigned int doSomething(unsigned int *x, int y)
{
    if(y)
    {
        printf("y is ok\n");
    }

    if(1)
    {
        printf("1 is ok\n");
    }

    return ((*x) + y); 
}
```

Please check if this works for you and then compare it with your program.
Make sure you've declared the function properly.

Comment: OP programme is compiled successfully in my mingw3.2.

Answer (score 2):

Try explicitly declaring it in main()

If not declared properly, Compiler assumes it returns int by default

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an `unsigned int` (x) added to an `int` (y) which can be a signed `int`. Without casting the second operand (y), this can result in undefined behavior if you intend to return only `unsigned int` in this function.

Comment: `x` is declared as `unsigned int`.

Comment: When an `int` is added to an `unsigned int`, the `int` is converted to `unsigned int` before the addition is carried out as part of the usual arithmetic conversions. The behaviour is completely defined [except for the exact sizes and representations of the involved types].